# Removing overlapping buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, overlapping-features

I wanna know how to do [this](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/2fa3e3416d06d61d85257125006b2533/41e83fb340bc258b85256cae00577bab?OpenDocument) in QGIS:

[image]

I've tried many ways, but still can't find the right solution.

Comment: Consider using Voronoi diagrams.  Animated examples appear at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/animating-a-voronoi-diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Don't remember if there is a specific tool, anyway if you need a powerful way to remove overlapping areas then just import your vector in a GRASS mapset, you can do it in the QGIS work environment using the QGIS/GRASS plugin. The GRASS vector model is fully topological so it just does not allow overlapping areas, that during the import are saved in a separate layer. After that you can export the GRASS vector with the "save as..." QGIS dialog.

Comment: Tried answer one -- imported to a GRASS set and then exported back to shapefile with Save As in QGIS -- but it made no difference, the overlapping layers persisted. Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need, but from link you shared it looks as full manually operation. In QGIS the same manipulation can be done with Split Features tool.